# How to display a canvas created with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, canvas

I want to display a a image dynamically depending on a simple jQuery post request. However, the post request works well, but the canvas is not displayed anyway.

I've tried like this:

```
$.ajax({type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://....'}).done(function (data) {
        // data is beeing recieved correctly, it is not empty
        var imageBase64 = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data;
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
            ctx2d = canvas.getContext("2d"),
            size = 64, c = size / 2 - 0.5,
            innerRadius = 5,
            outerRadius = 20;

        canvas.width = size;
        canvas.height = size;
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = imageBase64;
        ctx2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0);      
    });
});
```

Am I missing something? How can I display that newly created canvas?

Comment: You will have to append your created document element `canvas` anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're code seems correct, but you've only missed to append your created document element `canvas` on any DOM element. Try this please:

```
$.ajax({type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://....'}).done(function (data) {
        var imageBase64 = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data;
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
            ctx2d = canvas.getContext("2d"),
            size = 64, c = size / 2 - 0.5,
            innerRadius = 5,
            outerRadius = 20;

        canvas.width = size;
        canvas.height = size;
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = imageBase64;
        ctx2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0); 
        // Append your created canvas for example to the body of your DOM
        document.querySelector('body').appendChild(canvas);       
    });
});
```